# How to run service in background even app is close and auto-start permission is disable

Tags: android

Android background service is stop when app is remove from recent screen. Can any one help to make service that run always in background even app is close and auto-start permission is disable.

Some device has auto-start permission. If this permission is disable then service is not restarts when we close app from recent screen.

Comment: Are you sure `Service` stopped?. It actually restarts when App is removed from Recent apps. How do you know it stopped?

Comment: Yes I know but some device has auto-start permission. If this permission is disable then service is not  restarts when we close app from recent screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Services cannot run if the app is force closed, its a security issue-  there needs to be a way for a user to turn an app off.  This includes when an app is just installed (its installed into force stop state) and the user has to launch it to remove it from there before any service will run.

Comment: Service is stop when app is remove from recent screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom rom there is nothing we can do. You may see some app like Facebook and messenger are still running. they are running because they are white listed app for that rom. If u want your service to keep alive u can do something but this process also needs auto start permission.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //setupNotificationListenerForNewRequest();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Removed form task ??

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service.class));

}
```

Destroyed ??

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

hope these will help ...

Comment: So there is any way to enable auto-start permission programmatically?

Comment: Nope .. I am facing the same problem with my Xaiomi device, but u can open auto permission tab from your app. but u can't give permission on your own.